# find and replace string issues

Tags: vba, excel

I have some products information where I need to update master code using vba codes. My product codes are like **0001-11-22** all digits where the master code is **0001**, the first 4 digits. I want to replace some of the master codes so when I do sumifs function, it is calculating correctly.

So products that have master codes of 0046, 0548, 0540 and 0545 needs to be replaced by 0152, 0438, 0041 and 0041 accordingly. Meaning 0046 needs to be replaced by 0152 and both 0540 & 0545 needs to be replaced by 0041.

I did some research online and modified the codes to fit my condition but there are 2 issues. 1) It seems like it's replacing every cell that contain the value of search string and 2) it's replacing values as 41 not 0041. The pictures below show the two issues I mentioned. So 0041-00-00 originally had 0545-00-00 on it which I don't wish to update. I only want to update the Master Code column.

```
Sub test()

Dim ws99 As Worksheet
Dim LR99 As Long

Set ws99 = Worksheets("raw data")
LR99 = ws99.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

ws99.Activate



     'Master code
     ws99.Range("AH1") = "Master Code"
     With ws99.Range("AH2", "AH" & LR99)
     .FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[-26], 4)"
     End With

    'All values
   ws99.Range("AH:AH").Select
   Selection.Copy
   Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

   Dim v As Integer
v = Val(ws99.Range("AH2", "AH" & LR99))
Dim cid As String
cid = Format(v, "00")


Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim x As Long

fndList = Array("0046", "0548", "0540", "0545")
rplcList = Array("0152", "0438", "0041", "0041")


  For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
          ws99.Columns("AH:AH").Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
          LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

  Next x


End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Format(var, "00") to preserve leading 00s

Comment: Change xlPart to xlWhole

Comment: hi, i tried to use your suggestions but have issues with type mismatch on line 'v = Val(ws99.Range("AH2", "AH" & LR99'

Comment: ws99.Range("AH2", "AH" & LR99).Address   Val expects a string

Comment: And you may need to pad the string with zeros (to get len of 4) as they exit the array if trimmed in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with something like

```
ws99.Range("AH:AH").NumberFormat = "@"

For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
    for i = 2 to LR99
        if ws99.Range("AH" & i).Value = fndList(x) then
            ws99.Range("AH" & i).Value = rplcList(x)
        end if
    next i
next x
```

find method often gives problems

And actually to be clear you won't need all that code... I would change it like

```
Sub test()

    Dim ws99 As Worksheet
    Dim LR99 As Long, x As Long, i a Long
    Dim fndList As Variant, rplcList As Variant

    Set ws99 = Worksheets("raw data")
    LR99 = ws99.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    fndList = Array("0046", "0548", "0540", "0545")
    rplcList = Array("0152", "0438", "0041", "0041")
    ws99.Range("AH:AH").NumberFormat = "@"

    For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
        For i = 2 to LR99
            If Left(ws99.Range("H" & i).Value, 4) = fndList(x) Then
                ws99.Range("AH" & i).Value = rplcList(x)
            End If
        Next i
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your input I was able to get the first issue resolved but the second issue still persists. I am getting 41 instead of 0041. I am not familiar on how to use Format(var, "00")

Comment: I see. Edited!!

Comment: Sweet you saved the day!!